# Can't click directly on HTML form element , have to click below it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, shinyproxy

Troubleshooting someone's HTML/CSS/JS/Jquery/ShinyProxy code. 
Can't click directly on form elements like a radio button, instead I have to click in a region below the radio button to select it.  (see [Want to click on Red?  You have to click on Yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4PmC.png))

What would cause this sort of offset between mousepointer location and the rendered form elements?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code here - not a screenshot. How could we even begin to troubleshoot that?

Comment: Please provide the html and css code behind.

Comment: I think the css is messing up. Is there a way you can let me see your html and css in a fiddle or something?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to a regression bug in Chrome version 73, that affects some pages that use `iframe`. A fix is alredy committed and is planned to be part of version 74 release.

Please see relevant discussions and possible temporary solutions at https://github.com/openanalytics/shinyproxy/issues/139 and https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=945779